# Как передать значение по умолчанию в input date

Tags: html, bootstrap, flask, jinja2, flask-wtf

Использую flask-wtf и bootstrap 5, передаю в start_date тип datetime.date

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    {{ form.start_date(class="form-control", type="date", value=start_date) }}
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы по умолчанию стояло значение заранее определённой даты, как на скриншоте ниже
[image: Поле input с типом data, в котором стоит значение]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во views.py надо передать это значение в саму форму при том, что форма не была заполнена ранее

```
if not form.start_date.data:
    form.start_date.data = start_date
```